# On Android can select element positioned behind another

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Ive used absolute positioning and CSS3 animations so clicking a trigger div makes another animate to cover it. This is working fine except on my fairly old Android phone, when you click the div infront you can sometimes select an option input which is in the div behind it. Ive tried adding a z-index but the issues is still there. Thanks

Comment: Some code would be nice - at least to demonstrate what is happening - a http://jsfiddle.net/ would get you top marks

Comment: I cant post my actual code. This is an example of what I mean, but the issue isnt occurring with this fiddle so not sure how much help it will be. http://jsfiddle.net/Qw23H/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a CSS solution but ive done it with jQuery. Below are functions that I call to disable / un disable the input so it cant be selected.

```
function disableInputs () {
$('select').prop("disabled", true);
//alert('disabled');
}

function unDisableInputs () {
$('select').prop("disabled", false);
//alert('un disabled');
}
```